# I clicked on Mirror object but it went to a wrong place

Tags: modeling, mirror

Can someone help me wiith this? I need to mirror this "eye" object to the right side < , i select all by pressing A and i clicked on Mirror option , but the object mirrered down and not side as it should be , look:
[image]

it should be like this:

[image]

And i cant UNDO the item i mirrored because it cannot be selected , i tried crtl z but didnt work too, for so many times i closed blender and opened again thinking i did something wrong , but i dont wanna do it again :S can someone tell me how to undo this too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testings I figure it out - this must be your case, I think.

Before you use any modifier, ever apply transformations.

I rotated my mesh in object mode and applied the mirror and I got a bad mirror.

But after applying the rotation I got the desired mirror.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: i didnt find option here to reply to your asnwer i will do in the comments section here! i thank you  A LOT for your help because it worked just fine now it is where it should be!!!